# Is this Double U-Net overfitting?

Tags: cnn, convolutional-neural-network

I'm working on a undergraduate project with using deep learning. Currently, I'm trying to improve a model by modifying it. Model is [Double U-Net](https://github.com/DebeshJha/2020-CBMS-DoubleU-Net) and dataset that I'm using is DRIVE dataset. It consists from 20 images. My problem is validation score does not increase anymore. I think there is a overfit problem and also, I heard that is the max potential of network so I should try another dataset or model. Data separated 80% training and %10 validation. How can I improve result?

What I tried:

```
-Added one more U-Net network
-Using (128, 64, 32, 16) filter size
-Using (64, 32, 16, 8) filter size
-BinaryCrossEntropy loss function
-Added dropout exit of encoders with 0.5 value
-Added top, left, right and bottom symmetry augmentation for images, so total number of augmentation is 25
```

Augmentations (left-top is original image):
[image]

Results:

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

The U-Net is not overfitting it is just the training graphs are not smooth. This jittering in the training graphs can be removed by tweaking the learning rate of the model.